# How to get Module Title from Module in SuiteCRM?

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

So I have renamed Accounts module to Organisation module and need to do some customization, I am getting module name as 'Accounts' and I need to get its title here 'Organisation'.

How can I do this in SuiteCRM or Sugarcrm 6?

Comment: Where specifically are you still getting the module name of Accounts?

Answer (score 0):

You could take the original language file from

> modules/Accounts/language/en_us.php

copy it over to

> custom/Extension/modules/Accounts/Ext/Language/en_us.MyFileName.php

replace all the occurrences of "Account" in it and reformat the file so that only the needed keys get replaced and not the whole array of translations. So this

```
$mod_strings = array (
'LBL_ACCOUNT_NAME' => 'Account'
...
```

becomes

```
$mod_strings['LBL_ACCOUNT_NAME'] = 'Organisation';
```

After a `repair & rebuild` from the admin section the file will be combined into

> custom/modules/Accounts/Ext/Language/en_us.lang.ext.php

the new label will be showing.

Proceed the same way with all the other places you want to change a label...

Comment: Best practice would probably be to not override the entire contents of the language file, but only extend the specific labels you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I did as below to get the module title
translate('LBL_MODULE_NAME',)